# Extract Values from JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to extract some values from a Json but I have problems with the data between [ ]

```
{ 
  attrib1: ""es-BO"",
  attrib2: 2,
  Segment: [
  {
    inAttrib1: ""value1"",
    inAttrib2: ""value2"",
    inAttrib3: ""value3""
  }]
}
```

for the first values I'm using:

```
string attrib1 = request.GetValue("attrib1").Value<string>();
.
.
.
```

but when I'm trying to do:

```
string inAttrib1 = request.GetValue("inAttrib1").Value<string>();
```

doesn't work...what can I do?, or exists another way to do the same

Comment: That's not valid JSON, I checked it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). By the way, you shouldn't ever just say something doesn't work. Describe how it doesn't work, provide example output or tell us what exception you hit etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The data between (and including) `[]` is called an *array*. Before moving on it might be helpful to look at [JSON's home page](http://json.org/), specifically at the different data types available.

You need to navigate down to the `Segment` array, then get the first element, then that element's `inAttrib1` property:

```
string attrib1Value = request["Segment"][0]["inAttrib1"].Value<string>();
```

Or alternatively:

```
string attrib1Value = request.SelectToken(@"Segment[0].inAttrib1").Value<string>()
```

Comment: How do you handle null cases? What if you call `.Value<string>()` but the values isn't a string? What will happen?