# Loop through object to get values return from AJAX using jQuery and C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to loop through the object I received from jQuery AJAX method into my aspx.cs page.

My object structure (I get object[] of 5 objects)

[image: I get object[] of 5 objects]

I want to get the value of BusinessOwner (how to access these properties)

[image: how to access these properties]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this might help?

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IDictionary<string,object> rptBusDetails = new ExpandoObject();
        rptBusDetails["rptBusDetails"] = new List<object> 
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"BusinessOwner", "Mark"}, {"ChartReq", ""}}, 
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"BusinessOwner", "Tom"}, {"ChartReq", ""}}
        };
        var parent = new object[] { rptBusDetails };

        foreach(var node in parent)
        {
            var details = JObject.FromObject(node);
            foreach(var detail in details["rptBusDetails"])
            {
                string owner = detail["BusinessOwner"].Value<string>();
                Console.WriteLine(owner);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

[Updated]

Comment: thanks for your reply, Itried your way, but it shows cannot convert object to array at
"foreach (var thing in (Array)childNode)"

What I want is 

I am getting the object from my ajax post method in client side, I am getting and object array, which has json fields. I want to get the values of the fields. Below is my json string that is being formed as passed as object { rptBusDetails: [ [{ "BusinessOwner": "mark", "ChartReq": "", "ColorReq": "", "EmailList": "", "ReportApplication": "", "ReportAud": "", "ReportDelivery": "", "ReportDesc": "" }], }

Comment: Try converting that object to a JObject (instead of an array) using JObject.Parse (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject__ctor_2.htm) and then access properties via http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010085/1162991

Comment: no luck 

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

Comment: How about `JObject o = JObject.FromObject(object);` http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm?

Comment: worked like charm, thanks a lot
but how do I get the key and value from the JObject ?

Comment: Great! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010021/get-value-from-json-with-json-net/9010085#9010085 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494029/1162991

Comment: I updated the code. Mark as answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? something as easy as this should work, based on your question.

```
List<string> businessOwners = new List<string>();
foreach (object[] objArray in rptBusDetails) {
    foreach (object obj in objArray){
        businessOwners.Add((JToken)obj["BusinessOwner"].ToString());
    }
}
```

since you didn't say what you wanted to do with the BusinessOwner property, I put them in a list.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply, I want to get the value of Business Owner that is "Mark"

I tried your solution but it says "cannot apply indexing of type object"

Comment: @Sandy Right you're using a dynamic object when you really should be using JTokens, try casting the obj as a JToken. Why are you using object as a type anyways?

Comment: I am getting the object from my ajax post method in client side, I am getting and object array, which has json fields. I want to get the values of the fields. Below is my json string that is being formed as passed as object

{
 rptBusDetails: [
  [{
   "BusinessOwner": "mark",
   "ChartReq": "",
   "ColorReq": "",
   "EmailList": "",
   "ReportApplication": "",
   "ReportAud": "",
   "ReportDelivery": "",
   "ReportDesc": "",
   "ReportDisplay": "",
   "ReportFormat": "",
   "ReportFreq": "",
   "ReportFreqDesc": "",
   "ReportTitle": ""
  }],
  }

Comment: @Sandy Oh sorry I missed one of the levels you had! I didn't realize it was an array of arrays of JTokens. I corrected it now.

Comment: I tried again
var tempobj = (JToken)(obj[0])["BusinessOwner"];
Cannot apply indexing to object.

Should I try post the data in any other format than object, I am not sure how to ?

I have array of objects in my client side which I am trying to get into my webmethod in code behind

Comment: @Sandy Yeah I realized that right after I posted it, I made some changes to the code, looks like you tried it between my fixes.